# text file of data to csv file in python

Tags: list, python-3.x

i have text file with this type of information and i want save this information to be excel/csv any idea how to do it.in python. please help me.

```
2014-02-20 6127.15 6129.10 6086.45 6091.45 42.65 35.70
2014-02-19 6132.05 6160.35 6125.75 6152.75 34.60 -20.70
2014-02-18 6071.30 6141.70 6066.80 6127.10 74.90 -55.80
2014-02-17 6057.10 6080.65 6038.30 6073.30 42.35 -16.20
2014-02-14 6023.75 6056.40 5984.60 6048.35 71.80 -24.60
2014-02-13 6087.55 6094.40 5991.10 6001.10 103.30 86.45
2014-02-12 6085.35 6106.60 6077.40 6084.00 29.20 1.35
2014-02-11 6072.45 6081.85 6053.25 6062.70 28.60 9.75
2014-02-10 6072.80 6083.05 6046.40 6053.45 36.65 19.35
2014-02-07 6077.65 6079.95 6030.90 6063.20 49.05 14.45
2014-02-06 6028.35 6048.35 5965.40 6036.30 82.95 -7.95
2014-02-05 6004.25 6028.05 5962.05 6022.40 66.00 -18.15
2014-02-04 5947.60 6017.80 5933.30 6000.90 84.50 -53.30
2014-02-03 6058.80 6074.85 5994.45 6001.80 80.40 57.00
2014-01-31 6082.75 6097.85 6067.35 6089.50 30.50 -6.75
2014-01-30 6067.00 6082.85 6027.25 6073.70 55.60 -6.70
2014-01-29 6161.00 6170.45 6109.80 6120.25 60.65 40.75
```

how to add these data into excel cell wise.

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: i din't have any idea how to do..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with file.txt being your data, you can use [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) to read your file and write (in Python3) to data.csv file:

```
import csv
with open('file.txt', newline='') as csvfile, open("data.csv","w",newline='') as mycsv:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    wr=csv.writer(mycsv,delimiter=',', quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for row in reader:
        print(', '.join(row))
        wr.writerow(row)
```